# Rreplace the same character with two different outputs in GOOGLE SHEET

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Is it possible to use REGEXREPLACE to correctly write these latin last names (with accent mark)?

I have tried using this REGEX but it's not working:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE($C2,"Ã","í"),"Ã","ó"),"³","")
```

How would you solve it?

[SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qPRT-U8FqV2X_4_vidNhnMmyRic_0LWM/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116517467570837051476&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Thanks in advance.

`=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE($C2,"Ã","í"),"Ã","ó"),"³","")`

I expect to see the correct written version of those last names.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Further to the comment by @TheMaster. The `google-sheets` tag says quite clearly **`Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.`** BTW, the is also a free online service for markdown tables at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: please provide sample data (values to go in cell C2) as well as examples of successful outcomes

Comment: `I have tried using this REGEX but it's not working:` please include examples that are NOT working.

Comment: `$C2,"Ã","í"),"Ã","ó")` What is the objective of the second regexreplace function? the first pass, `"Ã","ó"`, will apply to **all** instances of "Ã"; so the second function, `"Ã","ó"`, is wasted since there won't be any remaining values of "Ã".